# How to get all possible combinations of a list’s elements(with limiting elements combinations) and multiple it?

Tags: python, combinations, multiplication

I want to multiply each combination of elements in a list, and store it in the same list, for example:

```
A=[0,1,3,5,7]

#generate this combination (only A[1]:A[3])
A[5]=A[1]*A[2] # 1x3=3
A[6]=A[1]*A[3] # 1x5=5
A[7]=A[2]*A[3] # 3x15=15
```

Then I want the output of to be

```
A=[0,1,3,5,7,3,5,15]
```

How do I get this done?

Comment: Use `itertools.combinations` and then `list.extend`

Comment: You don't really want to use range do you @AbdanSyakuro?  If not, perhaps edit the title

Comment: @pylang already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Patrick suggests, you can use `itertools.combinations` first:

```
 comb = list(itertools.combinations(A[1:4], 2))
```

And then extend your list as follows:

```
A.extend([cc[0] * cc[1] for cc in comb])
```

Comment: I had some problem with "unhashable type: 'slice' "

Comment: @AbdanSyakuro, is your `A` variable not a list as you specify in your question?

Comment: sorry my mistake, I tried it on other programs, in which the user must enter the variables

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having to import `itertools.combinations`, some simple for loops could suffice:

```
A=[0,1,3,5,7]

start=1
end=3

for ctr_a, a in enumerate(A[start:end+1]):
    for b in A[start+ctr_a+1:end+1]:
        A.append( a * b )

print(A)
```

gives

```
[0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 3, 5, 15]
```